# AutoScaling WinForm Display (Small, Medium)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scaling, dpi, autoscalemode

First and foremost, please forgive me but my screenshots are in French due to my Windows installation at work. It is still very easy to understand though. I'll include screenshots to make it more visually appealing.

Here's some background information:

- Windows 7 64bit
- Visual Studio 2010
- Default  display is 100%
- AutoScaleMode: **DPI**
- AutoSize: **True**

[image: Form properties]

My application is a windows form that was developped in a default (small - 100%) display. Like so:
[image: Small (default) display]

As you can see, the "Petite" or **Small** display is the default selection.

### Small Display - 100% (default)

Here is how my application looks with this setting. **This is the correct display**
[image: Perfect display]

### Medium Display - 125%

The red rectangles point out the unwanted empty space.
[image: Display at Medium or 125 percent]

I have tried:

- **Anchoring** / **Docking** my controls such as my split containers, table layout panels, list views **on Form_Load** *and* via the **UI**. This didn't work.
- Adding a split container to the form, and all controls respectively separated into it
- Adding Table layout panels, where all textboxes and buttons are located in their respective cells

I really thought it was having a scaling problem because of the anchoring and docking. Although that didn't seem to be the problem ... What seems to be having trouble is the Tab Control and Listviews ...

Some users (most) have their settings as the default (100%) but there are a few who have it at a Medium setting, causing this scaling issue. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue by putting the tab controls and list views in a tablelayoutpanel. Everything that wasn't scaled properly had to be put inside a TableLayoutPanel. I kept my `AutoScaleMode` to `DPI` and `AutoSize` to `True`

Be sure to dock everything in their parent containers.

Here's the document outline for the more visual (like me):

[image: Outline]

Answer (score 3):

I cant see your screenshots or links for some reason so I cannot visualize the problem. If scaling is the problem, try setting `AutoScaleMode` to `None`.

I recently had to do this because my winform app was image intensive and it would not render correctly on Medium Settings because I built it using the default Small Settnigs display.  Changing scale mode to `None` worked for me.

Comment: Really? That's weird ... Do they show as broken links or what? That sucks I put a lot of screenshots :(

Comment: Ah.. images blocked by work firewall apparently.. they show up on different network - sorry for false alarm :) - seeing screens, i doubt my answer applies

Comment: Thanks for the attempt anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Just click on the form and go to property pane. Find the Anchor element and click the dropdown. You click on all the lines in the square structure to become grey. Then click enter. Problem resolved.